# Picking image always gives landscape image

Tags: android, file, bitmap, image-gallery

I have used the following code to pick up an image from phone's gallery:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setType("image/*");
  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
  startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
    USE_LIBRARY_PIC_REQUEST);
```

In onActivityResult(), it gives the filepath, I tried getting bitmap using filepath, but it always gives it in landscape view. Is there a way to get that image in portrait view always?
Code for getting filepath:

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
```

This is how i got bitmap using file path:

```
Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
```

Comment: you problem is "You took a photo in portrait mode, then when it is loading, it get loaded in to landscape?" Or "You just wanted rotate all the photo while loading 90 degree?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

to  get original image you can use this method.

```
public static Bitmap getBitmap(String uri, Context mContext) {

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    Uri actualUri = Uri.parse(uri);
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];
    options.inSampleSize = 2;
    ContentResolver cr = mContext.getContentResolver();
    float degree = 0;
    try {
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(actualUri.getPath());
        String exifOrientation = exif
                .getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(cr.openInputStream(actualUri),
                null, options);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            degree = getDegree(exifOrientation);
            if (degree != 0)
                bitmap = createRotatedBitmap(bitmap, degree);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
}

public static float getDegree(String exifOrientation) {
    float degree = 0;
    if (exifOrientation.equals("6"))
        degree = 90;
    else if (exifOrientation.equals("3"))
        degree = 180;
    else if (exifOrientation.equals("8"))
        degree = 270;
    return degree;
}

public static Bitmap createRotatedBitmap(Bitmap bm, float degree) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    if (degree != 0) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.preRotate(degree);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(),
                bm.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    }

    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: exifOrientation is alway getting '0'